# Get Database VIEW metadata via JDBC

Tags: sql, database, jdbc, view

I want to fetch metadata information regarding a Database view.

I can find my view using the following code

```
DatabaseMetaData databaseMetaData = connection.getMetaData();
        String tableName = "";
        ResultSet rSet = databaseMetaData.getTables(null, databaseName, null, new String[] {TABLE, VIEW});
        while (rSet.next()) {
            tableName = rSet.getString(TABLE_NAME_COLUMN);
            if (rSet.getString(TABLE_TYPE_COLUMN).equals(TABLE)) {
                tableNames.add(tableName);
            } else if (rSet.getString(TABLE_TYPE_COLUMN).equals(VIEW)) {
                viewNames.add(tableName);
            }
        }
```

Now when i have the view name, i want to fetch the list of data columns in the VIEW.

I use the following code

```
ResultSet rSet = databaseMetaData.getColumns(null, databaseName, table, null);
        while (rSet.next()) {
            columnDefinitions.add(new ColumnDefinition(rSet.getString(COLUMN_NAME_COLUMN), getColumnClassName(rSet
                    .getInt(DATA_TYPE_COLUMN))));
        }
```

the concern here being that this query only returns the list of base columns from which this VIEW was derived. Say if my base table had 3 columns and i created a view if that table with 2 extra columns deriving information from the 3 base columns.

I want to fetch all 5 columns name and information. Is this possible ?
Is there any other method available to do this ?

Comment: You might be able to get the information you want by querying your database's data dictionary.  Exactly how you do this, and whether it is possible at all, depends on which database (e.g. Oracle, SQL Server, DB2, MySQL, PostgreSQL) you are using.  Which database are you using?

Comment: I am making this thing DB independent. Using JDBC/hibernate. If the solution needs to be DB specific, then the target list would include MySQL, MSSQL and oracle.

Comment: Have you tried using the view name instead of the table name in the call to `databaseMetaData.getColumns()`?  I've given this a quick play in Oracle and MySQL and this seems to work.